# What serializer to use?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, attributes, datacontractserializer

I was using DataContractSerializer and so far it provided everything I need.
Now I need two more features and I already know that they are not possible with DataContractSerializer.

1. I need to be able to serialize some fields as XmlComments
2. Some members should be serialized directly as Xml-Attribute in the containing object.

XmlSerializer neither supports opt-in nor does it support fields / privates which I need, so unfortunately it's out of the question.

Can I somehow make my own serializer that honors the existing "XmlAttribute"-Attribute and my custom "XmlComment"-Attribute while using DataContractSerializer as base?

Maybe there's already an third-party serializer out there that provides what I need? I didn't find one though.

I wouldn't mind writing a custom serializer but I want to reuse as much existing code as possible.

Comment: "XmlSerializer neither supports opt-in nor does it support fields / privates" -> why can't you expose the fields/privates as public properties?

Comment: I'm with loopedcode on this one. You should create a completely separate data model object who's singular purpose is the serialization/deserialization of _data_. Separately convert that data model to/from your business objects. Your business objects can this way maintain their private fields/implementations and your data model objects can focus on public properties or various XML attribute adornments to meet the schema you require.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair he wan't XML comments though... even with DTOs designed just for serialization that is going to require some custom serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XmlSerializer. You are just going to need to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) on objects that can't be handled by the default rules and do the heavy lifting yourself.  This is still simpler than rolling your own serializer IMO.